# Get columns only if it is not null is sql server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following rows.I dont want to select those columns whose entire value is null

```
col1   col2   col3
 1      2     NULL
 2      3     NULL
 3      4     NULL
 .      .     NULL 
 .      .     NULL 
 .      .     NULL
 100    101   NULL
```

For example,
I want to select only `col1` and `col2` since all the values of `col3` is null ie if `col3` contains any value other than null then `col1 col2 and col3` should be selected.Other wise `col1 and col2` should only be selected.

How to acheive the above scenaria in sqlserver

Comment: Why do you have a column full of NULLs in the first place?

Comment: What's the purpose of returning a dynamic set of columns?  Wouldn't you want to statically know the set of columns being selected?

Comment: The scenario  is the user want to see only those columns which are not null..

Comment: @SparAby: That sounds like a UI concern, not a database concern.  The UI technology can examine the data and conditionally show/hide columns.

Comment: Yes I han handle the scenario from the UI side.The problem is there could be thousands of data and I'm afraid that iterating through each row will affect the performance of the application.That's why I thought trying it via the db.

Comment: @SparAby - you can write a query that *helps* the UI by including information about whether each column contains nulls. That's separate from having to generate a dynamic result set. Do you want such a query?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a better/efficient way present but you can try the below which is mixed o bit TSQL script and dynamic SQL. teasted and it works fine. A sample code below.

```
create table test1(col1 int,col2 int);

insert into test1(col1) values(2),(3),(4)

declare @col1sum int, @col2sum int, @countrow int;

 -- This query will get you NULL count for all columns
select  @col1sum = sum(case when col1 is null then 1 else 0 end), 
@col2sum = sum(case when col2 is null then 1 else 0 end),
@countrow = count(1) 
 from test1;

 select @col1sum, @col2sum, @countrow; --for display

 declare @sql varchar(100);

  -- check for column null count < total count of rows
 if(@col1sum < @countrow)
 set @sql = 'select col1 from test1';
 else if(@col2sum < @countrow)
 set @sql = 'select col2 from test1';
 else
 set @sql = 'select col1,col2 from test1';

 exec(@sql); -- Finally execute the dynamic sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go the way that David suggests in the comments and do the *hiding* in the UI, but have the database do the work to help you out, you can use aggregate functions with windows to add some extra columns:

```
declare @t table (col1 int,col2 int,col3 int)
insert into @t(col1,col2,col3) values
 (1     ,2    ,NULL),
 (2     ,3    ,NULL),
 (3     ,4    ,NULL),
 (9     ,NULL ,NULL),
 (100   ,101  ,NULL)

 select
    col1,CASE WHEN MAX(col1) OVER () IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as col1_HasValues,
    col2,CASE WHEN MAX(col2) OVER () IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as col2_HasValues,
    col3,CASE WHEN MAX(col3) OVER () IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as col3_HasValues
from @t
```

Which produces the result set:

```
col1        col1_HasValues col2        col2_HasValues col3        col3_HasValues
----------- -------------- ----------- -------------- ----------- --------------
1           1              2           1              NULL        0
2           1              3           1              NULL        0
3           1              4           1              NULL        0
9           1              NULL        1              NULL        0
100         1              101         1              NULL        0
```

The `_HasValues` columns will be identical across all rows and tells you if *any* row has a non-NULL value in the preceding column. If it's `0`, you should hide the column in the UI.